# How to get a YTD dynamically in Google Sheets (Google Finance)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, google-finance

I want to display the YTD of a stock listed in C.

```
=(GOOGLEFINANCE(C5,"price")/INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(C5,"close","01/01/2021", today()),2,2))-1
```

I do not want to change `"01/01/2021"` each year to the current year. Is there any possibility to make something like `"01/01/YEAR(TODAY()"`.

Answer (score 2):

I got it: just leave the year out.

Solution: `=(GOOGLEFINANCE(C5,"price")/INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(C5,"close","01/01", today()),2,2))-1`